# Verify JWT with RSA Public Key in Node

Tags: node.js, jwt

Trying to verify a JWT using the public key, I'm writing some integration tests around this, but this is what I'm doing

Setup

```
const {privateKey, publicKey} = crypto.generateKeyPairSync("rsa", {modulusLength: 4096});
const privateKeyString = privateKey.export({type: "pkcs8", format: "pem"}).toString();
const publicKeyString = publicKey.export({type: "spki", format: "pem"}).toString();

let user = {email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'};

const token = jwt.sign(user, privateKeyString, {algorithm: "RS256"});
```

That gets passed to the following function:

```
jwt.verify(token, publicKeyString);
```

I've also tried with:

```
jwt.verify(token, publicKeyString, {algorithms: ['RS256']}
```

Both yield:

```
verify: JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
```

I've used JWT.io to validate the token, and also verifying the signature with both the public and private key. Using `jwt.decode` works correctly as well.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: works for me. `jwt.verify(token, publicKeyString, function(err, decoded) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(decoded);
      });
` I get null for error and then the decoded payload.

Comment: So this is bizarre. It's working for me too when I setup tests directly testing the function. However, if I call it through my Express API, the verify fails...and I have no idea why.

Comment: did you console log the keys? Maybe take out the `crypto.generateKeyPairSync`and just provide the keys as string.

Comment: I've actually created an integration test without superagent by calling the Controller function directly, and having it flow through the process. I also made a unit test against the actual function that does the validation, and both of those work without issue. As soon as Superagent is used, it fails, but only on verify. Decode works fine. A bit perplexed.

Comment: Was there ever found a solution to this problem? I am encountering the same problem, generating the keys with generateKeypairSync.